# Testing an array works with toEqual but not with toBe

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am testing whether or not an array is what I expect it to be using 
`toBe()`. It passes with `toEqual()`, but that isn't as good of a check 
as `toBe()` because I don't want any room for error in what is returned.

I have already tried a workaround using `toEqual()`;. However, while it works per se, I want `toBe` to pass as well because I want no room for error.

```
getAssignedChildren = () => {
    const { parent, allChildren } = this.state;
    const { children: assignedChildren } = parent || {};
    const assignedChildNames = [];

    if (!assignedChildren) {
        return [];
    }

    assignedChildren.forEach((assignedChildId) => {

        const childData = allChildren.find(
            (child) => child.childId === assignedChildId,
        );
        assignedChildNames.push(childData.childName);
    });

    return assignedChildNames;
};    





it("should get the assigned children for a given parent, push the 
names of said children into an array, and display the names of the 
children on the corresponding parent\b's detail page", () => {
    const { children } = parent;
    const { records } = allChildren;
    const props = {
        someStore,
    };

// allChildren is an imported mock data object
    const wrapper = createWrapper(ParentDetails, props, true);
    wrapper.setState({
        parent: { children },
        allChildren: records,
    });
    wrapper.getAssignedChildren();

    // TODO: Refactor toEqual to toBe in order to apply stricter 
equality checking
// for reference, the mock data object causes there to be a matched 
child-to-parent array to have a length of 5
// I need this toEqual to be a toBe
    expect(wrapper.getAssignedChildren()).toEqual([
        records[0].childName,
        records[1].childName,
        records[2].childName,
        records[3].childName,
        records[4].childName,
    ]);

    expect(children.length).toEqual(wrapper.getAssignedChildren().length);
```

The test passes with toEqual. However, toBe says:

> expected ['child1', 'child2', 'child3', 'child4', 'child5'] but got ['child1', 'child2', 'child3', 'child4', 'child5']. The console error message reads:  Compared values have no visual difference. Note that you are testing for equality with the stricter `toBe` matcher using `Object.is`. For deep equality only, use `toEqual` instead.

Comment: As it says `toBe` is using `Object.is`, which would return true only if the arrays are referentially equal. `toEqual` is what is to be used here

Comment: `toBe` is basically the same `===`. Once you are creating a new array inside your method (btw, you should use `map` instead of `forEach`), `toBe` cannot pass.

Answer (score 1):

Jest documentation states below:

> toBe uses Object.is to test exact equality. If you want to check the
>   value of an object, use toEqual instead.

`Object.is` gives whether 2 values are same value. In case of array, whether they have same reference or not.
That's why you need to use `toEqual` to `recursively checks every field of an object or array.`.

Documentation Link: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/using-matchers

Object.is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is

Comment: @m-greco Consider accepting and upvoting if answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Object.is checks for equality. See below code. it won't compare values of array.
I hope this clarifies your doubts about toBe and Object.is

```js
//it will be false as it will check for referential equality
console.log(Object.is([1,2,3], [1,2,3]))
var arr = [1,2,3];
//it will be true
console.log(Object.is(arr,arr))
//but below will be false
console.log(Object.is(arr,[1,2,3]))
//same goes for objects
var obj = {value:1};
//it will be true
console.log(Object.is(obj, obj));
//but below will be false
console.log(Object.is(obj, {value:1}));
```

: